# JSON.Net - Change $type field to another name?

Tags: json.net

When using Json.Net, I understand how to get the $type property into the rendered json, but is there a way to change that field name?  I need to use "__type" instead of "$type".

Comment: I need this too, for example [JSON-LD](http://json-ld.org) uses `@type`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like this is hardcoded as `public const string TypePropertyName = "$type";` in `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonTypeReflector` which is internal static class unfortunately.

I needed this myself, and the only thing I can think of is having custom modified version of json.net itself. Which is of course is a major pita.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have pretty much had to completely abandon the path I was headed down because of how hard Json.Net is to use in many cases.  This is just one example.

Comment: I am myself looking of how I on the server-side, that is written i C# and uses Json.NET, can deserialize JSON sent from an Android app using Jackson. In Jackson I can setup to use "$type", but it doesnt work anyway.

Answer (score 20):

[http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/22429](https://web.archive.org/web/20130410184516/http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/22429)

> "I would rather keep $type hard coded and consistent."

Consistent with what I wonder?

http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/21989

> I would rather not - I think this is too specific to me and I don't
>   want to go overboard with settings. At some point I will probably
>   implement this - [http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/21856](https://web.archive.org/web/20160803001559/http://json.codeplex.com/workitem/21856) - allowing
>   people to read/write there own meta properties in the JSON and you
>   could reimplement type name handling with a new property name. The
>   other option is just to modify the source code for yourself to have
>   that property name.

And more recently, [Issue #36: Customizable $type property name feature](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/36#issuecomment-8022339):

> I'd rather not

This is my solution...

```
json.Replace("\"$type\": \"", "\"type\": \"");
```

Comment: Your solution is awesome! ^_^

Comment: And still more recently (JamesNK closed this Jun 11, 2017): [Be able to support custom inheritance discriminator field #1331](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1331).

Answer (score 8):

I had to do this for my UI REST API as Angular.js [disregards](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1463) fields names starting with a dollar sign ($).

So here's a solution that renames `$type` to `__type` for the whole Web API and works both for serialization *and* deserialization.

In order to be able to use a custom `JsonWriter` and a custom `JsonReader` (as proposed in the other answers to this question), we have to inherit the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` and override the corresponding methods:

```
internal class CustomJsonNetFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public override JsonReader CreateJsonReader(Type type, Stream readStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
    {
        return new CustomJsonReader(readStream, effectiveEncoding);
    }

    public override JsonWriter CreateJsonWriter(Type type, Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
    {
        return new CustomJsonWriter(writeStream, effectiveEncoding);
    }

    private class CustomJsonWriter : JsonTextWriter
    {
        public CustomJsonWriter(Stream writeStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
            : base(new StreamWriter(writeStream, effectiveEncoding))
        {
        }

        public override void WritePropertyName(string name, bool escape)
        {
            if (name == "$type") name = "__type";
            base.WritePropertyName(name, escape);
        }
    }

    private class CustomJsonReader : JsonTextReader
    {
        public CustomJsonReader(Stream readStream, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
            : base(new StreamReader(readStream, effectiveEncoding))
        {
        }

        public override bool Read()
        {
            var hasToken = base.Read();
            if (hasToken && TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName && Value != null && Value.Equals("__type"))
            {
                SetToken(JsonToken.PropertyName, "$type");
            }
            return hasToken;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you need to register the custom formatter in your `WebApiConfig`. So we replace the default Json.NET formatter with our custom one:

```
config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
config.Formatters.Add(new CustomJsonNetFormatter());
```

Done.

Comment: I like this solution! With a small customization I no longer have to use the lengthy types names _Namespace.Type, AssemblyName_ but can also rewrite this ;-)

Answer (score 7):

when serializing, there is a nice way to override the property name:

```
public class CustomJsonWriter : JsonTextWriter
{
    public CustomJsonWriter(TextWriter writer) : base(writer)
    {
    }

    public override void WritePropertyName(string name, bool escape)
    {
        if (name == "$type") name = "__type";
        base.WritePropertyName(name, escape);
    }
}

var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
var writer = new StreamWriter(stream) { AutoFlush = true };
serializer.Serialize(new CustomJsonWriter(writer), objectToSerialize);
```

I haven't tried deserialization yet, but in worst case I could use:

```
json.Replace("\"__type": \"", "\"type\": \"$type\");
```

Comment: Do you have a similar solution for the reader? I am trying to deserialise objects, but the $types in my Json are pretty uggly/complicated and would like to rename them. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4):

We had a need for this so I created a custom JsonReader. We're are using rest in our MS web services with complex data models and needed to replace the "__type" property with "$type."

```
class MSJsonReader : JsonTextReader
{
    public MSJsonTextReader(TextReader reader) : base(reader) { }

    public override bool Read()
    {
        var hasToken = base.Read();

        if (hasToken && base.TokenType == JsonToken.PropertyName && base.Value != null && base.Value.Equals("__type"))
            base.SetToken(JsonToken.PropertyName, "$type");

        return hasToken;
    }
}
```

Here is how we use it.

```
using(JsonReader jr = new MSJsonTextReader(sr))
{
    JsonSerializer s = new JsonSerializer();
    s.DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat;
    s.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    s.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto; // Important!
    s.Binder = new MSRestToJsonDotNetSerializationBinder("Server.DataModelsNamespace", "Client.GeneratedModelsNamespace");

    T deserialized = s.Deserialize<T>(jr);

    return deserialized;
}
```

Here is our MSRestToJsonDotNetSerializationBinder that completes the compatibility between MS rest and Json.Net.

```
class MSRestToJsonDotNetSerializationBinder : System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder
{
    public string ServiceNamespace { get; set; }
    public string LocalNamespace { get; set; }

    public MSRestToJsonDotNetSerializationBinder(string serviceNamespace, string localNamespace)
    {
        if (serviceNamespace.EndsWith("."))
            serviceNamespace = serviceNamespace.Substring(0, -1);

        if(localNamespace.EndsWith("."))
            localNamespace = localNamespace.Substring(0, -1);

        ServiceNamespace = serviceNamespace;
        LocalNamespace = localNamespace;
    }

    public override void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        assemblyName = null;
        typeName = string.Format("{0}:#{1}", serializedType.Name, ServiceNamespace); // MS format
    }

    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        string jsonDotNetType = string.Format("{0}.{1}", LocalNamespace, typeName.Substring(0, typeName.IndexOf(":#")));
        return Type.GetType(jsonDotNetType);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also do it this way:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonSubtypes), "ClassName")]
public class Annimal
{
    public virtual string ClassName { get; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

You will need the [`JsonSubtypes`](https://github.com/manuc66/JsonSubTypes/blob/master/JsonSubTypes/JsonSubtypes.cs)
 converter that is not part of `Newtonsoft.Json` project.

Answer (score 1):

There is another option that allows to serialize custom type property name in `Json.NET`. The idea is do not write default `$type` property, but introduce type name as property of class itself.

Suppose we have a `Location` class:

```
public class Location
{
    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

First, we need to introduce *type property name* and modify the class as demonstrated below:

```
public class Location
{
    [JsonProperty("__type")]
    public string EntityTypeName
    {

        get
        {
            var typeName = string.Format("{0}, {1}", GetType().FullName, GetType().Namespace);
            return typeName;
        }
    }

    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Then, set `JsonSerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling` to `TypeNameHandling.None` in order the deserializer to skip the rendering of default `$type` attribute.

That's it.

**Example**

```
var point = new Location() { Latitude = 51.5033630, Longitude = -0.1276250 };

var jsonLocation = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(point, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
     TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None,   //do not write type property(!)
});
Console.WriteLine(jsonLocation);
```

**Result**

```
{"__type":"Namespace.Location, Namespace","Latitude":51.503363,"Longitude":-0.127625}
```

Comment: I don't see how deserializing will determine the correct type with your solution. Can you explain?

Comment: To deserialize, try `JsonCreationConverter`, e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom converter should get the job done.

```
public CustomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite => true;
    public override bool CanRead => true;

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
        Type objectType,
        object existingValue,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
        => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer,
        object value,
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jOjbect = (JObject)JToken.FromObject(value);
        jOjbect.Add(new JProperty("type", value.GetType().Name));
        jOjbect.WriteTo(writer);
    }
}
```