# JSON.NET - deserialize JSON into object, which class type is in inner field

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

Usually we deserialize using JSON.NET by this code

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CLASS TYPE> (text, settings);
```

Imagine, that we have such JSON request:

```
{
  "command" : "register_user",
  "params" : {
    "@c" : "register_params",
    "name" : "sdfsd",
    "email" : "sdfsd@ddkdk",
    "password" : "JDFffJJJd"
  }
}
```

How could we automatically detect that we need deserialize "name", "email" and "password" fields into one register_params object using JSON.NET?

Comment: This (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490345/json-net-change-type-field-to-another-name) appears related as it looks like you're using @c like JSON.NET normally uses $type.

Comment: Could you please provide link to example, which is using such meta-field? I found article, which explain different way and not very helpful: http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2012/02/json-deserialization-with-jsonnet-class.html

Comment: JSON.NET introduced a TypeNameHandling value which can be utilized in two ways; as an argument to the JsonSerializerSettings. In an attribute on the property you want it to apply to like this `[JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All)]`. It works by writing a $type into the JSON output. I don't know of any specific articles, but take a look at http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/SerializationSettings.html for an explanation of TypeNameHandling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the TypeName value "$type".

I've written two methods to do as such:

```
//T can be an interface or a derived type
public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string json) where T : class
//Uses "$type" to determine the object
public static object DeserializeObject(string json)
```

source:
https://gist.github.com/ricjac/b84a1d550cfe469f3945