# DataContractJsonSerializer and JsonConvert give different result

Tags: c#, json, json.net, silverlight-5.0

I have a method like this.

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer dataContractSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Message), this.knowTypes);
    dataContractSerializer.WriteObject(memoryStream, message);

    byte[] byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
    memoryStream.Close();
    return byteArray;
}
```

When I convert the byteArray to string the result is like below:
`{"__type":"Login:#Project.ProjectName.Sockets","Password":"F9AAD6B7CFBD2A756101","Username":"UserName"}`

This result is meaningful my server.

However I want to change this code with because of some character issues.

```
byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));
return byteArray;
```

Now I convert byteArray to string the result like:
`{"Username":"UserName","Password":"F9AAD6B7CFBD2A756101"}`

Also I have tried to use `JsonSerializerSettings`

```
 settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
 settings.TypeNameAssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Full;
 settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
```

and result is
`{"$type":"Project.ProjectName.Sockets.Login, ProjectName","Username":"UserName","Password":"F9AAD6B7CFBD2A756101"}`

What is the difference between DataContractJsonSerializer and JsonConvert and it is possible to get same result using JsonConvert.

Comment: Is it a possibility to change both serializing and deserializing end with `Json.NET`?

Comment: The format of Json.NET's type hints is hardcoded.  See [Format of 'Special Property' ($type) is hardcoded](https://json.codeplex.com/workitem/22429).

Comment: Possible duplicate?  [JSON.Net - Change $type field to another name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490345/json-net-change-type-field-to-another-name).

Answer (score 0):

Pass the following settings to the `DataContractJsonSerializer` and you should never get any type information:

```
DataContractJsonSerializerSettings settings = new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings()
{
    EmitTypeInformation = EmitTypeInformation.Never
};
```

Comment: I think the OP does want to emit type information, just in a different structure.

Comment: DataContractJsonSerializerSettings is for .Net 4.5 and later versions. Also I've forgot to say that I am using silverlight 5 so I cannot use `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings `