# Newtonsoft JSON.NET create a Type dictionary

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I have some Serialization code based on the Newtonsoft Json.NET package.
I serialize large amount of instances of few types, 
but JSON.NET add a tag e.g. `"$type": "complex_serializer_tests.SerializerTests+Node, complex-serializer-tests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",` to every element.

this adds a significant amount of size to the save-format, which i would like to eliminate.

I wanted to create a Type Dictionary, that will:
1. for every new type, assign an Id (integer)
2. and use it across the JSON something along the line of `"$type":#105`
while adding a type-id => type-name element.

I am sorry, this aint very specific,
but the problem is that I don't know how to address it and would love some guidance what topics should I read...

**EDIT** Clarification, I don't mind the `$type` property name, but it's content... instead of writing the assembly-full-qualified-name, i'd like to have an index that will represent it.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to make sure that `$type` is not a private variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON.Net - Change $type field to another name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490345/json-net-change-type-field-to-another-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define custom types using a custom [Serialization Binder](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm).

I.E.

```
public class MyBinder : ISerializationBinder
{
    public Dictionary<string,Type> Types { get; set; }

    public Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        // probably want to add some error handling here
        return Types[typeName];
    }

    public void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        assemblyName = null;
        // not very efficient, but could have a separate reverse dictionary
        typeName= Types.First(t => t.Value == serializedType).Value;
    }
}

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { SerializationBinder = new MyBinder { ... } };
```

Also, if it's adding type names where it can be inferred, you can specify when to add them in [JsonSerializerSettings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm#TypeNameHandling), though this may effect deserialization depending on the types you're deserializing to.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None };
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
```

Comment: Using a custom serialization binder is also more secure, see [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954) for details.

Comment: Thanks, reading about `ISerializationBinder` now, it seems to be the exact thing!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar requirements, here's how I did it:

- Create custom JsonConverter class
- Tell serializer to use you custom JsonConverter

### JsonConverter Example

Please note that this is alpha code and you will have to change parts esp. GetAllItemTypes that initilaizes the type key to type map (known limitation: needs lock).

```
public class TypePropertyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// During write, we have to return CanConvert = false to be able to user FromObject internally w/o "self referencing loop" errors.
    /// </summary>
    private bool _isInWrite = false;

    public override bool CanWrite => !_isInWrite;

    private static Dictionary<string, Type> _allItemTypes;
    public static Dictionary<string, Type> AllItemTypes => _allItemTypes ?? (_allItemTypes = GetAllItemTypes());

    /// <summary>
    /// Read all types with JsonType or BsonDiscriminator attribute from current assembly.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Dictionary<string, Type> GetAllItemTypes()
    {
        var allTypesFromApiAndCore = typeof(TypePropertyConverter)
            .Assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Concat(typeof(OrdersCoreRegistry)
                .Assembly
                .GetTypes());

        var dict = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
        foreach (var type in allTypesFromApiAndCore)
        {
            if (type.GetCustomAttributes(false).FirstOrDefault(a => a is JsonTypeAttribute) is JsonTypeAttribute attr)
            {
                dict.Add(attr.TypeName, type);
            }
            else if (type.GetCustomAttributes(false).FirstOrDefault(a => a is BsonDiscriminatorAttribute) is BsonDiscriminatorAttribute bda)
            {
                dict.Add(bda.Discriminator, type);
            }
        }
        return dict;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        _isInWrite = true;

        try
        {
            var type = value.GetType();
            var typeKey = AllItemTypes.First(kv => kv.Value == type).Key;

            var jObj = JObject.FromObject(value, serializer);
            jObj.AddFirst(new JProperty("type", typeKey));
            jObj.WriteTo(writer);
        }
        finally
        {
            _isInWrite = false;
        }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // we need to read and remove the "type" property first
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        var typeKey = obj["type"];
        if (typeKey == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot deserialize object w/o 'type' property.");
        }

        obj.Remove("type");

        // create object
        if (!AllItemTypes.TryGetValue(typeKey.Value<string>(), out var type))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"No type registered for key '{typeKey}'. Annotate class with JsonType attribute.");
        }

        var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(type);
        var value = contract.DefaultCreator();

        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException("No object created.");
        }

        using (var subReader = obj.CreateReader())
        {
            serializer.Populate(subReader, value);
        }

        return value;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return AllItemTypes.Any(t => t.Value == objectType);
    }
}
```

It's looking for a custom attribute "JsonType" and will use its Name properties value as key. If no JsonType is found, it will look for BsonDiscriminator attribute (from mongodb) as a fallback. You will havt to adjust this part.

### Tell Serializer About You JsonConverter

There are multiple ways to do this. I'm using attributes like so:

Use converter for items of a list:

```
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(TypePropertyConverter))]
    public List<PipelineTrigger> Triggers { get; set; }
```

See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm for details.

Or you could add JsonConverter attribute to you base class: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConverterAttributeClass.htm

Comment: Thanks for your post... Did you evaluate the ISerializationBinder as @EricDamtoft suggested and decided to use this approach?
or this was the only alternative you tried ?

Comment: I have to implement a defined API that uses a type property with a different name. Also I may have to add features to deal with more variations in json structure. But Eric is right, the ISerializationBinder approach should be much easier. Forgot about it.

Comment: thanks for sharing. I like alternatives... always something to learn :)