# Java Jackson Restlet JSON with polymorphic objects consumed by .NET (Newtonsoft) client

Tags: java, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I have a rest api app that is written in java (restlet, jackson). It's consumed using .net Newtonsoft.Json. The communication JSON contains polymorphic "@class" properties with "package.type" format. The JSON structure has arrays of different polymorphic derived class objects. The types are available in .net (not using converters for each type). So far what I am able to do in .net is set JsonSettings with `TypeNameHandling` with `FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple`, create a custom `SerializationBinder` that handles the java package format to the .net `FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple` format (`"NamespaceExample.TypeName, AssemblyName"`). So far so good, however I'd need to manually string replace "@class" with "$type" in the json before deserialization and vice versa after serialization for POST (update) operations. Do you know any better, more elegant way to do that replace automatically as part of the `JsonSettings`?

UPDATE:
Example:

```
public class CustomSerializationBinder : DefaultSerializationBinder //cool magic
{
    private string _assemblyName = "Assembly.Name";

    public CustomSerializationBinder()
    {
    }

    public override void BindToName(
        Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
    {
        assemblyName = null;
        typeName = serializedType.FullName;
    }

    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        var typeNameWithNamespace = $"{typeName}, {_assemblyName}";
        return Type.GetType(typeNameWithNamespace);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    private JsonSerializerSettings _settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        //Doesn't work directly as it produces a $type property, not a @class as in java
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
        TypeNameAssemblyFormat = FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple, //Exclude assembly version
        Binder = new CustomSerializationBinder()
    };

    [TestMethod]
    public void TypeNameHandlingTest()
    {
        var filePath = "resources\\json\\javaPolymorphicClassTyped.json";
        string json = "";
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        // Magic that sucks when deserializing
        var jsonFixedType = json.Replace("\"@class\":", "\"$type\":");

        Assembly.Name.BaseType[] holderArr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Assembly.Name.BaseType[]>(jsonFixedType, _settings);

        string jsonSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(holderArr, _settings);

        // Magic that sucks when serializing
        var jsonSerializedFixedType = jsonSerialized.Replace("\"$type\":", "\"@class\":");

        Assert.AreEqual(json, jsonSerializedFixedType);
    }
}
```

PS:
I know the question is not perfect, but I am sure it's clear enough for the polymorphic serialization gurus that I expect to help + not much time to waste on it :)

Thank you!

Comment: Please give an example to demo what you want to achieve.

Comment: Currently this is not implemented.  See [JSON.Net - Change $type field to another name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9490345/3744182) whose answers have several workarounds.

Comment: yeah, ok, so I've got the workaround in my question already. Thanks