# Default type discriminator for some subtypes in JsonDerivedType

Tags: c#, inheritance, json.net, default-value, system.text.json

For the following types' structure

```
public class Person { public string Name { get; set; } }
public class Adult : Person { public string Occupation { get; set; } }
... // many more subtypes
```

I need to have output like this (observe `__type` absence for the second entry):

```
[{"__type":"P","Name":"AbcPerson"},{"Occupation":"","Name":"XyzPerson"}]
```

It was easy to achieve this with `System.Web.Script.Serialization` using `JavaScriptTypeResolver`. And now I need to achieve this with `System.Text.Json`. To this end I can use this attributes:

```
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Person), typeDiscriminator: "P")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(Adult))]
```

Works good but in my case I have too many derived types and new are coming and I need specific discriminator only for some of them. Is it possible to add instances of `JsonDerivedType` only for some subtypes and fall back to some default for others?

Likely I will as well accept an answer for Newtonsoft but in this case I also need to know how to change `$type` to `__type`.

Comment: Not sure if [MS Docs - Handle unknown derived types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-8-0#handle-unknown-derived-types) might resolve the issue when a value of *FallBackToBaseType* for the enum [JsonUnknownDerivedTypeHandling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonunknownderivedtypehandling?view=net-8.0) is used?

Comment: There is no built-in way to change the Newtonsoft type discriminator, it is hardcoded to `"$type"`.  See [Customizable $type property name feature #36](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/36#issuecomment-8022339) as well as [JSON.Net - Change $type field to another name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9490345/3744182) which has some workarounds.